# Using Solr to search for lname 'smith', I am getting 'smitty and 'smits'

Tags: solr

I have defined this field in the schema as follows:`<field name="lname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

according to the docs in schema:

> The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.
>      It supports doc values but in that case the field needs to be
>      single-valued and either required or have a default value.

`<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />`

Yet when I query lname:smith, atleast in the top 10 responses I am getting smitty and smits but not smith. Why smith is not being returned.
However, when I try lname:smith* I get many results.
Any pointer to get the correct result is appreciated.
I am using Solr 6.3

Answer (score 1):

Did you reindexed the data after the change in the schema? Are you sure that you didn't have that field previously defined as `solr.TextField`? Because the `solr.StrField` stores the entire value as a single term in the index.

Use the [analysis section on the Admin UI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) to check which terms are being generated on your `lname` field, and check that you've reindexed the data after the schema change. Do you have some other special component defined in the update handler that you're using?